# How to set the value to a variable in the script(.js) file from the script in aspx file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Im having a variable 'multi' , the same name i used within the js file. I need to set a value to the variable within my aspx page and pass it on to the javascript file. Couldnt find any help.

aspx script code

```
    var itemdata = [];
    var multi;
    //var plot;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ChartBinder.asmx/BindChart",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                //alert(multi);

                var resultObj = $.parseJSON(response.d);
                multi = resultObj;
               // alert(resultObj.Pie);
                multi.Trend = resultObj.Trend;
                //alert(multi.Trend);
                $.getScript('Scripts/highcharts.src.js', function () {
                    DrawPie(resultObj.Pie);
                    DrawTrend(resultObj.Trend);
                    // do something here

                });

            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
```

js script

```
(function () {
   var seriesCount = window.multi.Trend.length;

   var newcolors = [];

   for (i = 0; i < seriesCount; i++) {
      newcolors[i] = multi.Trend[i].color;
   }
})
```

Comment: If you declare `var multi` (global scope) before you include the .js file then you should already have access to it from the .js include.

Comment: Im loading the script only after fetching the data. Still not getting. Can u check the updated code?

Comment: Can you show your entire html code that applies (more specifically, the areas where the inline JS is written and where the include is brought in)

Comment: Off topic: You don't need to do the `multi.Trend = resultObj.Trend;` assignment as you have already done `multi = resultObj;`. On Topic: Does `alert(multi.Trend);` produce the correct value? Also, in your .js file you are using `window.multi.Trend.length;` Can you try without `window.` (although I am not exactly sure how the global var will work with a file brought in via AJAx.

Comment: @webnoob... Tried like what you mentioned. It worked. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`multi` should be in scope globally for use within that your include because you have declared it in `Global` scope i.e the top of the document outside of a function block.

Try changing

```
var seriesCount = window.multi.Trend.length;
```

to

```
var seriesCount = multi.Trend.length;
```

Off Topic:

You don't need to do the `multi.Trend = resultObj.Trend;` assignment as you have already done `multi = resultObj;`.

Answer (score 0):

`multi` in your example is declared in `Global` scope therefore available to any other JS in your applicaiton:

```
var multi; //global but must be included before code referencing it

(function () {
    var multi; //local
})
```

Based on your comments:

```
....
$.getScript('Scripts/highcharts.src.js', function () {
      DrawPie(resultObj.Pie);
      DrawTrend(resultObj.Trend);
      // do something here
      DoWork();
 });
 ...

 function DoWork()
 {
     var seriesCount = window.multi.Trend.length;
     var newcolors = [];
     for (i = 0; i < seriesCount; i++) {
       newcolors[i] = multi.Trend[i].color;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you confirm that is still the case when the file has been loaded via JQuery `$.getScript('Scripts/highcharts.src.js', function () {})`

Comment: rick schott... It's not working. What you'd written under the DoWork part is actually within the js file which im loading dynamically :(

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable of required datatype in your code behind(.aspx page)

In Code behind(.aspx page):

```
private string multi = "New";

public string Multi
{
    get { return multi; }
}
```

In javascripts:

```
var multi='<%=Multi%>';
//Do your stuffs here
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the code behind. It's a scope issue with JS vars. The ASPX part is misleading, he just means a HTML page.